# How to size an icon according to parent in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-container

I want to size an icon inside a container to be the size of that container so that it would not be small in larger devices due to hard coding the size value. I was trying something like this

```
Container(
  child: Icon(
    Icons.beach_access,
    size: double.infinity,
  )
)
```

Comment: I want to set the size of Icon, with alignment property on Container I can only align the child

Comment: You could try using a [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) around the Icon provided you have set the dimensions of the Container surrounding the Icon correctly. I would recommend using MediaQuery to get the dimensions of the screen and set the height/width of the container appropriately for the screensize.

Comment: The container filling the whole screen or inherit size from another widget? If from another widget then add that widget code in your question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want the size of the icon to meet the ends of its Container parent, you can place it in a FittedBox

```
Container(
  child: FittedBox(
     child: Icon(
        Icons.beach_access,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

You can change the fit property of the FittedBox to adjust some sizes and change alignment.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html